# Retrieving height and width of image from MySQL db

Tags: php, mysql, html, codeigniter

I have the url of the image location in a MySQL table. How would I retrieve the height and width of that image and plug it into the below img tag?

```
<img id="profileImg" alt="" height="96" width="87" src="<?=base_url().$row1->imgURI?>" />
```

Answer (score 2):

With http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

```
<?php
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize(base_url() . $row1->imgURI);
?>
<img id="profileImg" alt="" height="<?=$height?>" width="<?=$width?>" src="<?=base_url().$row1->imgURI?>" />
```

Also it'd be nice if you could derive the local path for the image file to avoid having to access the file via its url.  But I'll leave that up to.

Comment: Sweet. thanks man. Also is it possible to decrease the size by a percentage?

Comment: `height="<?=$height*0.9?>" width="<?=$width*0.9?>"` for 90%

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819524/a-very-good-php-image-resize-script-suggestion

Answer (score 0):

E.g. by using GD library function getimagesize(): http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the actual `width` and `height` stored in the database you can use [getimagesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php):

```
<?php
  $image = base_url().$row1->imgURI;
  $size = getimagesize($image);
?>
<img id="profileImg" alt="" height="<?=$size[1];?>" width="<?=$size[0];?>" src="<?=$image;?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest retrievable using the [getimagesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) function:

```
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize ( base_url() . $row1->imgURI );
<img id="profileImg" alt="" <?=$attr?> src="<?=base_url().$row1->imgURI?>" />
```